# Reduce and get sum on Dictionary containing custom object based on Key

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, mapreduce, flatmap

I have an dictionary `var dic = [TimeInterval: [CustomObject: Double]]()`

`TimeInterval` is a timestamp. `CustomObject` is an object with property `id` inside (of type `String`). And `AudioLevel` is a double.
I succeed to print object inside with:

```
for (key, values) in dic {
    for value in values {
        print("\(key): participant id : \(value.key.id) ... AudioLevel: \(value.value)")
    }
}
```

It prints in my example :

```
1581361504.064956: participant id : id1 ... AudioLevel: 1.8426420022371925
1581361504.0642018: participant id : id2 ... AudioLevel: 0.0030890756301589217
1581361504.065456: participant id : id2 ... AudioLevel: 4.256374635644427
1581361504.061193: participant id : id1 ... AudioLevel: 1.744451095262131
```

Now I would like to have an dictionary that contains `[CustomObject: Int]` where `Int` is the rank of the participant. Here `id2` will be first `(4.256374635644427 + 0.0030890756301589217` > `1.744451095262131 + 1.8426420022371925)`

Maybe I have to do a reduce based on `id + sum` of audiolevel, and after to `flatMap` to retrieve my `CustomObject`?

Comment: What does "rank" mean?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Rank is an Int based on AudioLevel sum (if sum of AudioLevel for id1 is greater than sum of AudioLevel for id2, rank will be 1 for id1 and it will be 2 for id2).

Comment: So is `TimeInterval` irrelevant to the output?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica yes I don’t need TimeInterval

Comment: So it looks like there's 6 simple parts to this: 1) Flatten out the top level dictionary, to get rid of the grouping by time interval. 2) Group by custom object, 3) sum the `AudioLevels` per custom object, 5) sort them, 6) convert the ordered result into a dict of custom object to rank. Which parts of that can you implement yourself?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I succeed the 1) dic.flatMap { $0.value } . After I think I have to group with .map ? I tried map { $0.key.id == $1.key.id } to group by CustomObject.id but that's not correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207547/discussion-between-vjardel-and-alexander-reinstate-monica).

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Can you post an answer ? I can't succeed to filter with key.id. After I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
dic.forEach { print($0.value) }
```

Comment: That doesn’t answer at my problem sorry

Comment: @saqlainbhatti: please add some context how this could help. Just posting code is not very helpful.